# Can't switch GPU driver Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm on Ubuntu and I got a NVidia GT1050 graphica card.
The issue is that I'm not able to switch GPU driver as I want, the options are in grey and there is nothing explained. Can someone tell me what to do or to look in order to fix it ? Thanks in advance

Screenshot of the software driver menu

[image: Driver menu]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
open terminal and enter:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

It will show you the available drivers for your graphics card. To install the drivers automatically, enter:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

wait for the proccess to finish then reboot.